# I want to create a button that will load a music file from the users computer to a div using just HTML, css, and JavaScript. Is that possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, file

I obviously have more code but I just want an idea of what I’m supposed to do, somI won’t put it all in.

```
  <!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>PlayBackingTracks</title>
  
  

  

</head>

<body>
  

   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you want the user to click a button to initialise the browser window so they can upload their own music or did you want your program to look into the users files by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide much to work with in your example but I've created a snippet that might help.

Run the snippet below:

```js
//declare elements as vars
var audioUpload = document.getElementById("file");
var audioLink = document.getElementById('audioLink');
var audioSource = document.getElementById("audioSource");
var audioControl = document.getElementById('audio');

//attach event listener to audioUpload input
audioUpload.addEventListener("change", function() {
  uploadAudio(this);
});

//function that will upload audio
function uploadAudio(input) {
  var reader;
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      audioLink.setAttribute('data-value', e.target.result);
      audioLink.innerHTML = "Click to play"
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

//function that will play audio after clicking link
function play(element) {
  audioSource.src = element.getAttribute('data-value');
  audioControl.load();
  audioControl.play();
};
```

```html
<p>Upload your audio file:</p>
<input type="file" id="file">
<br/><br/>
<div>
  <a id="audioLink" href="#" onclick="play(this)" data-value=""></a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<audio controls="controls" id="audio">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
</audio>
```